# Prove that if $S$ is closed under $\wedge$ and every $\alpha \in S$ is satisfied then $S$ satisfied

Tags: logic

Let the infinite set $S$ be closed under $\wedge$ (for every $\alpha,\beta\in S$ exists  $\alpha\wedge\beta\in S$ ).

Prove that if $S$ is closed under $\wedge$ and every $\alpha \in S$ is satisfied then $S$ satisfied.

Now, I don't have any idea on how to start this proof, I know that I need to use the compactness theorem somehow but I don't know how. I hope someone could help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the use of the letter $\alpha$ imply that only some of the elements of $S$ are convered by "every $\alpha\in S$"? Otherwise it would seem to be _by definition_ that if every member of $S$ is satisfied, then $S$ is satisfied -- no matter whether it is closed under conjunction or not.

Comment: Or, hmm, do you perhaps mean _satisfiable_ when you write "satisfied"?

Comment: Is this for propositional logic, first-order logic, or something third? Do you have a proof system with a completeness theorem for that logic? Do you have the compactness theorem?

Comment: Yes I need to use the compactness theorem somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean *satisfiable* when you write *satisfied*:

In order to use the compactness theorem you need to show that every *finite* subset of $S$ is satisfiable. However, because $S$ is closed under conjunction you know for every finite $\{\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n\}\in S$ that $(\phi_1\land\cdots\land\phi_n)\in S$ too. And because that conjunction is satisfiable, an interpretation/structure/value assignment that satisfies the conjunction will also satisfy each of the $\phi_i$s. So the compactness theorem applies.

Comment: But you proved that each proposition in $S$ is satisfiable, that doesn't mean that every finite subset of $S$ is also satisfiable.

Comment: @LiziPizi: Yes, because for any finite subset there is a _single_ proposition in $S$ that contains everything in the finite subset as conjuncts. In other words, given that $\phi_1\land\cdots\land\phi_n$ is satisfiable, then the assignment that satisfies that will satisfy the entire subset $\{\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n\}$.